# How to get entire array as string?

Tags: javascript

I need to get entire array result as a clear string like: `namegenderage`, but can't figure out how
I tried:

```
var arr = ["name","gender","age"];
var string = arr.toString().replace(",","");
console.log(string);
```

log result should be string like `namegenderage` without quotes and brackets  but I get this result `"namegender,age"`

Comment: Use `.join("")`

Comment: `var arr = ["name","gender","age"];
arr.join('');`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method:

```js
var arr = ["name","gender","age"];
var string = arr.join('');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: thanks for quick response that solved my problem. thanks again :)

Comment: @GuramiNikolaishvili no problem.